# Magnet moving in electric field

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, velocity

[image]

Consider a magnet moving with a velocity $v$ in an electric field (voltage of 1000KV,distance between electrodes as 10 cm).

So my question is what will happen? Will magnet feel a force against it or will electrodes will feel a force?

Also consider this whole setup is in space with no other force.

Answer (score 3):

The magnetization of a magnet is part of the magnetization-polarization tensor $$M^{\mu \nu} = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & c P_x & c P_y & c P_z \\
 -c P_x & 0 & -M_z & M_y \\
 -c P_y & M_z & 0 & -M_x \\
 -c P_z & -M_y & M_x & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ for the magnet shown all of the $P_i$ are zero in its rest frame. So in a frame where it is moving the magnetization-polarization tensor transforms to $$ M'^{\mu \nu} = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & -\frac{v \gamma  M_z}{c^2} & \frac{v \gamma  M_y}{c^2} \\
 0 & 0 & -\gamma  M_z & \gamma  M_y \\
 \frac{v \gamma  M_z}{c^2} & \gamma  M_z & 0 & -M_x \\
 -\frac{v \gamma  M_y}{c^2} & -\gamma  M_y & M_x & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$ where $\gamma$ is the usual Lorentz factor for a frame moving at $v$ relative to the magnet's rest frame and the $M_i$ are in the magnet's frame.

Note that the $M_x$ produces no polarization at all, but there is some z polarization produced by the $M_y$. This polarization will result in a torque being applied by electric field between the plates. However, this torque will be very small. First, most of the magnetization will be in the $M_z$ direction, so it will only be whatever imperfections exist in the magnet or its alignment. Second, it is divided by $c^2$ so it is quite small unless the magnet is moving at highly relativistic velocities.

So, ideally there will be no torque applied to the magnet, but if there is any imperfection in the alignment or in the magnetization of the magnet there will be a small polarization which will result in a small amount of torque